# Use JSF, JPA, JTA, JAAS, CDI, Bean Validation with Tomcat?

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jpa, cdi, jta

Is it possible to use the following APIs with tomcat (as a lightweight server):

```
JSF, JPA, JTA, JAAS, CDI, Bean Validation.
```

Comment: Yes, it is. But it's up to you to configure them to work properly. At least for JSF, JPA and CDI, you just drop the relevant jars in WEB-INF/lib and they will work.

Comment: Thanks. but can I use Java transactions without EJB.

Comment: Better think of TomEE instead (Tomcat's successor). Why do you want to avoid EJBs, by the way? EJBs not only provide transaction management but many more features like security, pooling, concurrency management...

Comment: Thank you @Tiny for your help. I just want to avoid using a heavyweight app server and instead use declarative and programmatic transactions and security. which I think is possible with tomcat. Also  spring framework provides the same services without the need for an app server. I am wrong?

Comment: App servers are no longer heavy-weight. Take a look at WildFly or GlassFish and you're ready to go. Even when you go the hard way and add lots of libs to Tomcat, you'd be still missing the container glue code.

Comment: @Tiny: TomEE is not Tomcat's successor. TomEE extends Tomcat into a full app server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yes](http://tomee.apache.org). [Except of JAAS](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html).

​​​​​​​​